# Writing entire classes to Python files (and replacing user input)

Tags: python

Basically, I need to write an entire class to a new .py file. The only problem is that two important variables inside the class rely on user input. When I write the class to the file I need to have the actual number/string where the user input is instead. Here is an example of what I currently have:

```
class CreateClient:
    def writer(self):
        file = open('client_test.py', 'w+')
        file.write(Client)
        print("File created")

class ClientConfig:

    def hostvar(self):
        inhost = str(input('Enter the listener hostname: '))
        return inhost

    def portvar(self):
        inport = int(input('Enter the port: '))
        return inport

class Client:
    def examp(self):
        host = ClientConfig.hostvar(ClientConfig)
        port = ClientCOnfig.portvar(ClientConfig)
```

As you can see I need Client to be writed to a new file, except it will write

```
host = ClientConfig.hostvar(ClientConfig)
port = ClientCOnfig.portvar(ClientConfig)
```

instead of what I need (i.e host='127.0.0.1', port = 9999). Is there any way I can do this, possibly use the operation 'replace'? If I attempt to access the host or port variable by doing Client.examp.host it won't work, so I don't see how I could use replace.

Comment: pass your variable entered by user to hostvar function as args

Comment: Could you be a little clearer please? Is it just `Client` that needs to go somewhere else? Also, why are you passing `ClientConfig` as a parameter to those functions?

Comment: You should write a [MCVE], what you've written now isn't really writing python source as you're suggesting. Plus, why would you need to do that? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Coldspeed The entire class 'Client' needs to be written to a new .py file. If I don't pass ClientConfig in the brackets I get a 'parameter unfilled: self' error.

Comment: Okay, @sS5H you're doing that wrong, but no problems. That can be fixed. What is your other issue? Who needs to have  host='127.0.0.1', port = 9999? Where is this entered? Is it taken from a file? Is it taken from user input? Do you provide it?

Comment: @pvg I am trying to make a script that will create a reverse shell client, but it needs to put the host and port input into the script as numbers/strings before it writes it to the file.

Comment: you can assign like `self.host = ClientConfig.hostvar(ClientConfig)` and then you can access like `client.host`. Also, if you're not using `self` in `hostvar` method, make that method as `staticmethod` then you can use it like `self.host = ClientConfig.hostvar()`

Comment: The actual code is rather long, but if required I can post it to clarify what is happening.

Comment: @pramod I am doing print(Client.host) and I get an AttributeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CreateClient

Here' you're calling `file.write(Client)` where you pass the class as a parameter. Assuming you want to write the code to another file, this is definitely something you don't want to do, because it just doesn't work*. I suggest you just copy-paste the code yourself into a new file and save it.

<sub>* This is because, if you want to save python objects, you'll need to convert them into a bytes stream. The best way to do this is using the `pickle` module, but this is not relevant for your problem</sub>

#### ClientConfig

Here, you have a choice. As @pramod suggested, you could convert these methods to static. Or, you could leave it be, and I'll show you how to call these accordingly in `Client`.

#### Client

Here's a solution for if you don't want to use static methods:

```
class Client:
    def examp(self):
        c = ClientConfig()
        self.host = c.hostvar()
        self.port = c.portvar()
```

And the alternative definition for this class, if you want to use static methods has been given by pramod.

---

### Creating a new python file [as per requirement]

```
import random
class CreateClient:
    __client_str = '''class Client:\n\t\n\t\tdef examp(self): self.host = %s; self.port = %d\n'''

    def writer(self):
        c = ClientConfig()
        host = c.hostvar()
        port = c.portvar()
        file = open('client_test%d.py' %random.randint(1, 999999), 'w')
        file.write(CreateClient.__client_str %(host, port))
        print("Client created")
        file.close()
```

Invocation from within some python script:

```
import os
os.system("python cilent_test<some_number>.py")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The entirety of class 'Client' would need to somehow to written to a new file in a function, otherwise there wouldn't be any purpose to what I'm trying to achieve. I don't know if this is remotely possible, however.

Comment: @sS5H Do you want the source code into a new file? Or do you want some object of `Client` in a new file?

Comment: @sS5H What are you trying to achieve? Why are you trying to write a new source file? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Coldspeed I need Client's entire block of code put in a new file for this to work. My goal is to essentially make a function that can create a new working Python script in a separate file

Comment: @sS5H You should consider creating a new instance of `Client` and saving _that_ in a new file. You can then use it as you wish. The alternative method, that you wish to do, is to save the definition of `Client` in a huge string, then write it to a new file, and then invoke that file using `subprocess` or `system`. Very painful.

Comment: @Coldspeed Would creating a new instance of Client allow me to pass it into write() as a string and then put it into a new file? Would it be something like cclient = CreateClient()                                             cclient2 = cclient.__class__
cclient3 = cclient2() ?

Comment: @sS5H No it would not. Please see my answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Coldspeed that code gives me    name '_CreateClient__client_str' is not defined

Comment: @sS5H my bad. It should be `CreateClient.__client_str` inside the function. Check my edit. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Coldspeed This block of code works to print what is specified into a new file, however, I am wondering if I can still find a way so that instead of it printing self.host = c.hostvar() it would actually print self.host = (whatever the user actually entered)

Comment: @sS5H Yes there is. You need to call ClientConfig from CreateClient, get the host and port there and then insert it into the code for Client. Please check my edit.

Comment: @Coldspeed Thank you, this was precisely what I was looking for

Comment: @sS5H Cheers. Glad to hear.

Comment: @Coldspeed The real class 'Client' (not the example code) is actually 50 lines of code, however. I don't suppose there is an easier way to write this out when making the new instance, is there?

Comment: @sS5H You could always paste the contents into a multiline string :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClientConfig:
    @staticmethod
    def hostvar():
        inhost = raw_input('Enter the listener hostname: ')
        return inhost
    @staticmethod
    def portvar():
        inport = int(input('Enter the port: '))
        return inport

class Client:
    def examp(self):
        self.host = ClientConfig.hostvar()
        self.port = ClientConfig.portvar()
```

Example:

```
>>> client = Client()
>>> client.examp()
Enter the listener hostname: 127.0.0.1
Enter the port: 8000
>>> client.host
'127.0.0.1'
>>> client.port
8000
```

Note: If you're not going to use `self` object inside `hostvar` or `hostvar`, I strongly recommend using `staticmethod`.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code. When I try to write the class Client to a file I get a TypeError that it has to be a string, not a type. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: have you updated your `ClientConfig` class with same as this one?